# Ubuntu 18.04 Python 3.7.5 can't install tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install tensorflow 2.2.0 but without luck:

`sudo pip3 install tensorflow==2.2.0` gives me the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
```

Please advise how can I solve this issue, I have checked almost all the Q&A here without luck.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7.5

Answer (score 1):

From [git](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39130#issuecomment-623335820)

> TensorFlow 2 packages require a pip version >19.0. Could you please upgrade pip using the below command and let us know if it works.
>
> `pip install --upgrade pip.`
>
> For more information please check this TensorFlow guide. Thanks!

Try running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`
And then running the install.
Did this help?

Comment: @tornkeo I have pip 20+ and pip3 9+ versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Ubuntu 18.04, you're in luck: that's an LTS version of Ubuntu, and you can install the [Lambda Labs stack](https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software). That's what I would recommend. That'll handle everything from your drivers to the Python stack. Only thing is: this installs Lambda Labs onto your native `/usr/bin/python` install. That's typically what I want, but maybe you'd prefer a more containerized version. That you should look into Docker, Kubernetes, etc.